# Homebridge v2 devices not showing in Home app

Tags: raspberry-pi, home-automation, smartthings

I can’t seem to find my Homebridge v2 devices in the Home app!

Homebridge is installed on a Raspberry Pi, as well as the web GUI and the homebridge-smartthings-v2 plugin. The Homebridge app is installed in the Smartthings app on my iPhone and I selected two devices in Homebridge and saved.

How do I then see these two devices in the Home app so I can add them there? Do I need to add something else to the config.json file?

Here is the daemon.log file:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tail -f daemon.log
Jan  8 14:34:41 raspberrypi rngd[322]: stats: FIPS tests speed: (min=4.682; avg=6.870; max=7.093)Mibits/s
Jan  8 14:34:41 raspberrypi rngd[322]: stats: Lowest ready-buffers level: 2
Jan  8 14:34:41 raspberrypi rngd[322]: stats: Entropy starvations: 0
Jan  8 14:34:41 raspberrypi rngd[322]: stats: Time spent starving for entropy: (min=0; avg=0.000; max=0)us
Jan  8 14:49:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Homebridge...
Jan  8 14:49:19 raspberrypi homebridge[15987]: [1/8/2020, 2:49:19 PM] Got SIGTERM, shutting down Homebridge...
Jan  8 14:49:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: homebridge.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=143/n/a
Jan  8 14:49:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: homebridge.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan  8 14:49:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Homebridge.
Jan  8 14:50:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Homebridge.
Jan  8 14:50:10 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:10 PM] Loaded config.json with 0 accessories and 3 platforms.
Jan  8 14:50:10 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:10 PM] ---
Jan  8 14:50:10 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:10 PM] Loaded plugin: homebridge-config-ui-x
Jan  8 14:50:10 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:10 PM] Registering platform 'homebridge-config-ui-x.config'
Jan  8 14:50:10 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:10 PM] ---
Jan  8 14:50:13 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:13 PM] Loaded plugin: homebridge-ring
Jan  8 14:50:13 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:13 PM] Registering platform 'homebridge-ring.Ring'
Jan  8 14:50:13 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:13 PM] ---
Jan  8 14:50:14 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:14 PM] Loaded plugin: homebridge-smartthings-v2
Jan  8 14:50:14 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:14 PM] Registering platform 'homebridge-smartthings-v2.SmartThings-v2'
Jan  8 14:50:14 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:14 PM] ---
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:15 PM] Loading 3 platforms...
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:15 PM] [Config] Initializing config platform...
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:15 PM] [Config] Spawning homebridge-config-ui-x with PID 16672
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:15 PM] [Ring] Initializing Ring platform...
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:15 PM] [SmartThings-v2] Initializing SmartThings-v2 platform...
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: Homebridge Version: 2.4
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: SmartThings-v2 Plugin Version: 2.1.5
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: Checking Package Version for Updates...
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:15 PM] Loading 0 accessories...
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: Configure Cached Accessory: Security Alarm, UUID: c3f254e2-85d5-4602-9813-25452e80e35b
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: Setup Payload:
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: X-HM://0023IX8JIMK71
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: Scan this code with your HomeKit app on your iOS device to pair with Homebridge:
...
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: Or enter this code with your HomeKit app on your iOS device to pair with Homebridge:
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:                        
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     ┌────────────┐
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     │ 033-44-254 │
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     └────────────┘
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:                        
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: Fetching SmartThings-v2 Devices. NOTICE: This may take a moment if you have a large number of device data is being loaded!
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: 2020-01-08T20:50:15.762Z '[FileStreamRotator] Failed to store log audit at:' 'logaudit.json' 'Error:' { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'logaudit.json'
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1190:35)
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at Object.FileStreamRotator.writeAuditLog (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge-smartthings-v2/node_modules/file-stream-rotator/FileStreamRotator.js:246:12)
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at Object.FileStreamRotator.addLogToAudit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge-smartthings-v2/node_modules/file-stream-rotator/FileStreamRotator.js:320:27)
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge-smartthings-v2/node_modules/file-stream-rotator/FileStreamRotator.js:437:36)
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:15)
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge-smartthings-v2/node_modules/file-stream-rotator/FileStreamRotator.js:483:20
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:   errno: -13,
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:   syscall: 'open',
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:   code: 'EACCES',
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]:   path: 'logaudit.json' }
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: New LogFile Created | newFilename: /var/lib/homebridge/homebridge-smartthings-v2-2020-01-08-14.log
Jan  8 14:50:15 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:15 PM] Homebridge is running on port 51826.
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: NOTICE: setting temperature_unit to (F)
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: NOTICE: Updating Global Values | HubIP: 192.168.1.10 | UseLocal: true
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: WARN: Devices to Remove: (0)
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: Devices to Update: (1)
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: GOOD: Devices to Create: (0)
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: Loading Existing Device (Security Alarm) | (alarmSystemStatus_9da00d0e-6ae7-4a73-b1f7-10433f8f7a58)
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: ALERT: Total Initialization Time: (2 seconds)
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: NOTICE: Unknown Capabilities: []
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: SmartThings DeviceCache Size: (1)
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: WebServer Initiated...
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: Sending StartDirect Request to SmartThings | SendToLocalHub: (true)
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: Direct Connect Active | Listening at 192.168.1.80:8000
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: SmartThings-v2 Hub Communication Established
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: SmartThings-v2 Hub Communication Established
Jan  8 14:50:17 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: SmartThings-v2 Hub Communication Established
Jan  8 14:50:18 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: SmartThings-v2 Hub Communication Established
Jan  8 14:50:18 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:18 PM] [Ring] Configuring 1 cameras and 1 devices for location "Shavano Park" - locationId: ae6fb12d-d377-431c-4d14-3c458a7be038
Jan  8 14:50:18 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:18 PM] [Ring] Adding new accessory doorbell_v4 Front Door
Jan  8 14:50:18 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:18 PM] Front Door is running on port 35019.
Jan  8 14:50:18 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: [1/8/2020, 2:50:18 PM] Please add [Front Door] manually in Home app. Setup Code: 033-44-254
Jan  8 14:50:24 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: INFO: INFO: Your plugin version is up-to-date
Jan  8 14:50:24 raspberrypi homebridge[16635]: NOTICE: Sending Plugin Status to SmartThings | UpdateAvailable: false
[Config]Homebridge Config UI X v4.6.7 is listening on :: port 8080
```

Update:
Seems I had an incorrect token to talk between Home and Homebridge. I also had to clear the Homebridge cache by deleting everything in the *persist* and *accessories* directories. All devices are now in the Accessories tab of the Homebridge web GUI. But, now I see **some** of my devices in Home but not all of them, my Kwikset door locks do not show up. And, my two light switches are not active even though they show up in the Home. Is there some trick I am missing?